# Changing the button to a different background onClick

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to get this button to change to a different background, 'linear-gradient' that has an image behind it. It's an audio playbutton.

You press it, it goes on, you press again if goes off.

**initial class** = What you first see 
(Only linear-gradient background, no image behind it)

**pause class** = What you see after you click it
(Transparent linear-gradient background, with image behind it)

**play class** = What you see after you click it again
(Transparent linear-gradient background, with image behind it)

**pause class** = What you see after you click it
(Transparent linear-gradient background, with image behind it)

The svg button changes from initial to pause, to play, back to pause, then play, but the transparent linear-gratient background doesn't change from the **initial class** background.

Can someone please help me get this code to work right. I've been trying everything and haven't been able to get it to work. It turns on and off, but the linear background classes (pause, play) with a background image behind it those **backgrounds** never appear after you click, it just stays on the **initial class** background, and never changes from it. This is what the issue is.

I forgot to mention, I would need to be able to place this code somewhere, twice. This is the background image that goes behind the transparent linear-gradient background. The initial class doesn't get an image, only the second two, play, and pause. This **isn't** currently in the  Full Code right now, I'm trying to figure out where to place it.

```
, url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x266');
```

This is how the (initial, pause, play) buttons are set up independently from the button code.

https://jsfiddle.net/k9qscyda/4/

initial:

```
<svg class="initial" style=" border: 3px solid #0059dd;padding:76px 85px 76px 85px;cursor: pointer;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px );"
width="90" height="108" viewBox="0 -3 85 120">
  <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:black; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
</svg>
```

Pause:

```
<svg class="pause" style="border: 3px solid #e77d19; padding:94px 100px 94px 100px;cursor: pointer;background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x266');"
width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 16 14">
  <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z"
  fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
```

Play:

```
<svg class="play" style="border: 3px solid #e77d19;padding:94px 100px 94px 100px;cursor: pointer;background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px ), url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x266');http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 16 14">
  <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.7623zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z" fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
```

**The Full Code is Below**

https://jsfiddle.net/31exzq4y/5/

This is the order in which it works.

**class="initial"**
[image]

**class="pause"** 
[image]

**class="play"**
[image]

 **Code:**

```html
<button id="playButton2" style="display:block; width: 266px; height: 266px; cursor: pointer;background-image: linear-gradient( to right,#000000 83px,#0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, #000000 86px, #000000  174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, #000000 177px ); border: 3px solid #0059dd;"
onclick=" 
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
    var player = document.getElementById('player2');
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .initial').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='none';
    player.volume=1.0; if (player.paused) {
    playButton2.style.background = 'background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px )';
    playButton2.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px'; 
    playButton2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
    playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
    document.querySelector('#playButton2 .pause').style.display='inline-block';
    player.play();
    } else {
    playButton2.style.background = 'background: linear-gradient( to right,transparent 83px,#e77d19 83px, #e77d19 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #e77d19 174px, #e77d19 177px, transparent 177px )';
    playButton2.style.border='3px solid #e77d19';
    playButton2.style.padding = '94px 100px 94px 100px'; 
    playButton2.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    playButton2.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playButton2.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'; 
    document.querySelector('#playButton2 .play').style.display='inline-block';
    player.pause();
    }">

  <svg class="pause" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 16 14">
    <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.762c1.577 1.462 2.57 3.544 2.57 5.858 0 2.314-.994 4.396-2.57 5.858l.65.763c1.79-1.644 2.92-3.997 2.92-6.62S14.735 2.024 12.945.38zm-2.272 2.66l-.65.762c.826.815 1.34 1.947 1.34 3.198 0 1.25-.515 2.382-1.342 3.2l.652.762c1.04-1 1.69-2.404 1.69-3.96 0-1.558-.65-2.963-1.69-3.963zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z"
    fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="play" style="display: none;" width="60" height="72" viewBox="0 0 16 14">
    <path d="M12.945.38l-.652.7623zM0 4v6h2.804L8 13V1L2.804 4H0zm7-1.268v8.536L3.072 9H1V5h2.072L7 2.732z" fill="#1ed760 " fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="initial" width="90" height="108" viewBox="0 -3 85 120">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #e77d19; stroke-width:3px;color:black; " d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
  </svg>
</button>

<audio id="player2" style="display:none;">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** TURN DOWN SPEAKERS BEFORE CLICKING!!!

Comment: @mplungjan I read this too late! Scared me haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the background to an invalid value so it's being ignored. Change the lines to remove the extra `background:` text:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/31exzq4y/6/

Changes specifically are:

```
from: playButton2.style.background = 'background: linear-gradient( [...etc];
to:   playButton2.style.background = 'linear-gradient( [...etc];
```

and the same for the else block.

Here it is with the background image: https://jsfiddle.net/31exzq4y/7/

You needed to add `https://` in front of the url  and escape the quotes.

Comment: Can you tell me where I place this part of the code please. , url('http://via.placeholder.com/266x266');

Comment: Thank you so much. Greatly appreciated.